# Insert new rows of sheet1 based on number of counts rows in sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba, insert, range, region

I want to insert new rows below row 6 of sheet 1 based on count number of rows ( eg. range(a7:a100)) of sheet 2. I have another data on a1200

However after run the code . Sheet 1 insert 11844 new rows in stead of what I count in sheet2.

I think the code recognize the range (inset row) based on the current region or used range instead of what I request.

Could anyone help to solve it.

Comment: Please add your code, so we can get a better picture of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Also make sure you're qualifying your ranges with the sheet, e.g. `Worksheet("Sheet3").Range("A1:A10")`...

Comment: This is part of the code:

Comment: This is part of the code:. 

LR = worksheets(“Sheet2”). Range (“a7”).end(xldown).row. 
Worksheets(“sheet1”). Range(“A10:AV10”).copy      
Worksheets(“a11:av11” & LR).insert shift = xldown